# How can I open calendar .ics files in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icalendar

I am trying to download and open .ics file in my app.

I found few question, and here's some code I am using

```
// NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"http://www.nmsd.wednet.edu//site/handlers/icalfeed.ashx?MIID=607" ofType:@"ics"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://www.nmsd.wednet.edu//site/handlers/icalfeed.ashx?MIID=607"];
UIDocumentInteractionController *dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
dc.delegate = self;
[dc presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Nothing at all happens. no errors at all. Would it be easier to look for a library to achieve this.

Comment: FYI - your http URL is not a file URL. `UIDocumentInteractionController` is meant to be used with local files, not remote files.

Comment: What do you actually want to happen after the ics file is downloaded?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I tried both, I want to implement a calendar feature in my app. I am trying to use these link to maybe populate the native calendar. I have no clue to be honest, am I on the right path? please advise

Answer (score 8):

If you have a link to remote `.ics` file, then prepare it for `Safari`.

Let's suppose that you have a link to `iCal` file:

```
"pl-dev2.office.org/events/sync.ics?t=90613b6c7f8".
```

Just add prefix `webcal://` to your link.

**Swift**

```
let link = "webcal://pl-dev2.office/events/sync.ics?t=90613b6c7f8"

let webcal = NSURL(string: link)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(webcal)
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *link = "webcal://pl-dev2.office/events/sync.ics?t=90613b6c7f8"

NSUrl *webcal = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:webcal];
```

Safari will sync it in your Calendar app for You.

Comment: how can an http url be changed to webcal:// ??

Comment: calshow:// is used to open calendar from app [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];

Comment: and there seems to be no other way to open the calendar app with the required ics file.. Do let me know how to open the ics file which i download from app / UIWebView and display the calendar app showing contents of the ics file downloaded..

Comment: That works, but it uses the URL as the calendar name.

Is there any query param I can add to the webcal url to pass a custom calendar name or does that have to come from the ics file itself?

Comment: But this asks you to add a calendar, but how can you add an event in your current calendar from the .ics file? (to do in swift code the same thing that Safari does when you open an URL that points to the .ics file )

Comment: @AndreiF you could open the url with SFSafariController, you can check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

The @Bartłomiej Semańczyk is adding a calendar, if you want to add a event you can open url with SFSafariController

```
let link = "https://www.apple.com/v/apple-events/home/p/built/assets/event.ics?d=3213214324313"
let url = URL(string: link)!
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I just need to figure out how to "auto" dismiss the SafariVC after the Calendar Event gets added

Answer (score 0):

You use `NSURL fileURLWithPath` with an URL string as parameter although it expects file path. Change it to `NSURL URLWithString`.