# Swift .ics file is not being added to calendar in swift 4

Tags: swift

In my app I need to use .ics files from url. I am getting url of .ics file from api and on taping a button, the url will open as:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(link.url!)
```

On hitting the url on browse, it will ask for adding .ics to calendar. This functionality is working with a demo link made by me..a .ics file that I have placed in dropbox and made a tiny url. But this functionality is not working with the url that I am getting from the api response. The url opens but it shows a blank page. What can be the reason??

UPDATE :->

There is popup blocked on my iPhone so, the url was opening but was showing blank page. Now I know there is nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Can you share the the link?

Comment: pplease try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315548/how-can-i-open-calendar-ics-files-in-ios

Comment: The file in Dropbox is local.

Comment: @Adarsh KC I added webcal:// to my url now it is not opening in browser and showing an alertbox with message "Could not subscribe to the calendar ....from url name"

Comment: But you didn't mention it in the question. If you have added anything how will we know that.?

Comment: Add a url for more clearance of the question